# Getting Filter.OnAuthorization to run before Controller.OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing site which has a base controller class for all of its controllers which overrides the implementation of `OnAuthorization`. In the simplest cut down form:

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    //Do Stuff
}
```

This all works fine and well and does what it wants at the right time. I now want to add a new global authorization that will run before all other authorisation attributes. For test purposes this attribute looks like this:

```
public class TestFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var text = "debug point";
        return;
    }
}
```

And is added to the Global Filters like this:

```
filters.Add(new TestFilterAttribute());
```

My problem is that the `OnAuthorization` of the controller always seems to run before my filter's one. Is there any way that I can change this? I've tried playing with the order property that you can set when adding it to the global filter collection but that doesn't seem to help.

I could probably move the logic of the Controller's `OnAuthorization` into a new filter attribute when order would probably be usable but I'd rather avoid major code restructuring if there is an easier way to do it.

I've been searching for information on the `Controller.OnAuthorization` method but the best I have found is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx which only talks about filters. I had assumed that they would work the same way on Controllers but they seem to be getting treated specially, in particular not respecting the order (not even `int.MinValue` gets in first so its not just that the controller has a very low order by default).

So any suggestions on how to get an auth filter to run as the very first thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution used was to refactor the code. I took all of the methods that can be run on a filter attribute (eg `OnAuthorization`, `OnActionExecuting`, etc.) and moved them onto attributes named for the classes they came from. So the `OnAuthorization` from `BasicController` became the same method on `BasicControllerAttribute`.

These attributes were then applied to the controllers and the attributes are then inherited by all of the classes that subclass from BasicController which essentially maintains the same functionality.

However the attribute can have its `Order` set that allows you to play around with the running order however you want.

My takeaway from this was to never override those methods on the controller and to always use attributes. :)

Comment: Good lesson. I have always liked filter attributes. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: Yeah, since starting on this path I've made loads of filter attributes to do all sorts of things (various security tests that would otherwise end up being put individually in each relevant action). Next thing I am considering is attributes to expand IDs passed in to their full objects. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a related problem with the Controller.OnAuthorization and the AuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization methods order of execution.

- The short answer is: **you can't override that Controller.OnAuthorization
  runs prior to other filters**.
- Detailed answer on the question 'why is it so?' is in the code from
  ASP.NET MVC sources below.
- There is also nice blog post on **[filter ordering](http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2011/05/14/MVC3-Filter-Ordering.aspx).**

Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved. See [License.txt](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#License.txt) in the project root for license information.

[FilterProviders.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FilterProviders.cs)

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class FilterProviders
    {
        static FilterProviders()
        {
            Providers = new FilterProviderCollection();
            Providers.Add(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            Providers.Add(new FilterAttributeFilterProvider());
            Providers.Add(new ControllerInstanceFilterProvider());
        }

        public static FilterProviderCollection Providers { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

[ControllerInstanceFilterProvider.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerInstanceFilterProvider.cs)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public class ControllerInstanceFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            if (controllerContext.Controller != null)
            {
                // Use FilterScope.First and Order of Int32.MinValue to ensure controller instance methods always run first
                yield return new Filter(controllerContext.Controller, FilterScope.First, Int32.MinValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its good to see some code to back up my findings. I tried to find it but this stuff seems to get into a bit of a maze of abstractions. :)